# How to check content type of input (xls) file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I have to read a `.xlsx` file in C#. I am doing as follows. But my row can have string or double.

```
Input Excel
Test file

1  v1  c1   -3.99
```

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    Excel.Range range;

    string str;
    int rCnt = 0;
    int cCnt = 0;

    xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

    for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
    {
        for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
        {
            str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2 ;
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
    }

    xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
    xlApp.Quit();
}
```

Now I am getting an error in the following statement: How do I check whether the row object is double or string?

```
string str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object value = x.Value2;

string str = value as string;
if (str != null) {
    // I am string
}

double? d = value as double?;
if (d != null) {
    // d.Value is double
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try to parse it into double if it fails use string:

```
if(!double.TryParse(input, out result))
    resultString = input.ToString();
```

then you could check if resultString.IsNullOrEmpty to decide if you use the double result or the string resultString.

Comment: Sorry, but makes no sense for me. Why don't you use `result`, and what for do you convert string `input` to string again?

Comment: Furthermore `double.TryParse` accepts only string input, i.e. `input` must be `string`, can't be `object`.

Comment: You can try to use `try { double d = double.Parse(objectValue); } catch { }` but it's much slower rather than operators `as` or `is`.

Comment: It is because the `result` is not a double value, because the function failed, otherwise you would use `result` and it will be a double. The only problem with this is that a `string` can look like a `double`. You can alway change `input` to `input.ToString()` in the function. That will solve your object string problem

Comment: @Jaques: Convert boxed double to string and then convert/parse again to double? I see that's a way to make Gambrinus's answer meaningful, but still I don't think it's a good solution. You need just unbox the double.

Comment: @abatishchev I never said it was a good solution, but you said it didn't make sence, so I cleared up the confusion :). Your answer is the best one.